# Regarding data read from TCP connection

Tags: java, tcp

I am making a client socket connection with a hardware device. I am sending a command to this connection to be process by hardware. Now as a acknowledgment or as a reply, the hardware sends a response.
 The application sends a command to the connection periodically say in 10 seconds.

Now there exists a problem randomly that the response won't gets synchronized with the sent command from the application. I was thinking of this as hardware specific but to my surprise, when I see the response by connecting putty to the same hardware at same port, I can see that response always gets synchronized. This looks like putty under the hood using some criteria to map the request to response.

Below is the programming steps that I am using to send a command to hardware device:-

```
            Socket clientSocket = new Socket(<IPADDRESS>, 4001);
    DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(
            clientSocket.getOutputStream());
    BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            clientSocket.getInputStream()));
    while (true) {
        try {
                            //Get command randomly from array enums for test
            Random r = new Random();
            Commands[] array = Commands.values();
            String command = (String) array[r
                    .nextInt(Commands.values().length)].getCommand();
            outToServer.writeBytes(command);
            Thread.sleep(500);
            while (!inFromServer.ready()) {
            }
            System.out.println("COMMAND "+command+", SERVER RESPONSE: "
                    + inFromServer.readLine());
            Thread.sleep(1500);

        } catch (SocketTimeoutException se) {
            //Handle Exception
        } catch (SocketException se) {
            //Handle Exception
        }
```

Can anybody gives a advice how the synchronization of response with request can be achieved as mechanism like putty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putty doesn't know any more about your device than you do. The problem is in your code. Get rid of the `ready()` test and the `sleep()`. Just call `readLine()`, if you can be sure that the device sends lines, otherwise just call `InputStream.read().`

Answer (score 1):

Remove the thread sleep, and rewrite read like this:

```
String line;
while ((line = inFromServer.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println("COMMAND "+command+", SERVER RESPONSE: "
                + line);
}
```

This code can still hang, if the device sends the last message without the newline character `\n`. Your original code skipped the input.

The main problem is with this line:

```
 while (!inFromServer.ready()) {
```

[`InputStreamReader#ready`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html#ready()) is OK to use only when you have other means to *know* that all the data has been sent:

> Tells whether this stream is ready to be read. An InputStreamReader is ready if its input buffer is not empty, or if bytes are available to be read from the underlying byte stream.

The first message will get read, but that empties the buffer, and when the second message arrives your code isn't reading anymore. You would have to have as many loops as there are messages from device, and that's not practical, at least. And in that case also, it would probably not work all the time.

On the other hand the [`BufferedReader#readLine`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine()):

> **Returns:**
>
> A String containing the contents of the line, not including any line-termination characters, or **null if the end of the stream has been reached**

will read until *all the data that was sent* has been read. But if your device send no new line character, then this method will never read the line - the code will hang with all the data in the buffer. In that case you should use [`InputStreamReader#read`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html#read()) as EJP suggested:

> **Returns:**
>
> The character read, or **-1 if the end of the stream has been reached**

**I strongly suggest that you read the [IO Streams](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/streams.html) official tutorial.**

Generally speaking, waiting is not done by `Thread.sleep` and [busy waiting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting) (executing empty statements), e.g.:

```
while (true) {}  /*or*/ while(true);
```

The CPU is executing the empty statement, and it could be doing some other work while waiting on this one to complete. It is a bad practice.

**If you want to know more on how to implement waiting I recommend reading the [official concurrency tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/) or [this one](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaConcurrency/article.html) for a broader approach on the matter.**

Comment: `DataOutputStream.flush()` does nothing unless the stream it is wrapped around is buffered, which it isn't in this case. It isn't buffered itself. Agree your second point.